# C# Изменение указанных при компиляции значений программы

Tags: c#, компиляция

У меня есть приложение с заданной переменной, к примеру

```
string str = "example";
```

Само собой она без каких либо доп файлов храниться в exe-шнике программы вместе с присвоенным значением. Могу ли я изменять ее уже после компиляции? В частности я хочу сделать отдельную программу конфигурации, которая меняет в программе с переменной значения. И каждый раз программа открывается уже с заданными перемеренными, будто в первый раз.

Такого эффекта можно добиться и чтением ini файла с конфигом, то мне не нужны лишние файлы в папке с программой, только exe-шник.

Для вышеописанного необходима рекомпиляция, или можно как-то изменить тот самый string из вне?

PS: задача именно в изменении самой программы. Это значит, что она должна в итоге запускаться без каких либо дополнительных файлов и действий, как обычный exe.

Comment: Если значений немного, можно передавать их как аргументы командной строки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можно подробней? Это нужно делать при каждом запуске программы?

Comment: Да, при каждом.

Comment: Теоретически можно менять значения в экзешнике. Можно написать программку для этого. Но любой антивирус зарежет её. К тому же, рядовому пользователю (не админу), нельзя писать в папку Program Files, где по идее должна быть ваша софтина. А главное: используйте файл настроек и не парьтесь.

Comment: Используйте ресурсы и функции/инструменты для их редактирования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не должны менять константы в исполнимом файле. Дело в том, что вы не знаете, где и как такая константа будет использована. Например, компилятор C# обычно объединяет одинаковые константы в одну, так что изменения в одной константе могут привести к очень странным последствиям.

Пример:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoTerribleHack();
    Console.WriteLine("привет");
}

static unsafe void DoTerribleHack()
{
    string s = "привет";
    fixed (char* p = s)
    {
        p[0] += '\x6';
        p[2] += '\x16';
        p[5] -= '\xe';
    }
}
```

Программа выводит, как некоторые уже догадались,

```
хрювед
```

Поэтому я бы очень не рекомендовал менять ваш скомпилированный файл. Правильное место для конфигурации — дополнительный файлы, например, App.config.

---

Пример для App.config:

Сам файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1"/>
    </startup>
    <appSettings> <!-- эту часть вы добавляете: -->
        <add key="greeting" value="привет" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

В проект добавляете ссылку на System.Configuration.dll, и пишете:

```
var greeting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["greeting"];
Console.WriteLine(greeting);
```

Да, это больше одного файла.

Comment: Почему уж тогда не стандартные Settings? С Application scope

Comment: @АндрейNOP: По идее, можно. Насколько я понимаю, `Settings` не предназначены для редактирования, но может быть, я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Application scope нельзя редактировать из кода, но в самом app.exe.config перед запуском никто не запрещает менять данные руками. Settings удобнее - типизация, автосгенерированный код для использования...

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Типизация — удобнее, возможно. Но вроде же они для этого не предназначены? А чтобы передать _просто одну строку_, достаточно и простого текстового файла (и проще). Так что вопрос в том, как _правильнее_.

Comment: Хм, а для чего тогда они предназначены?

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Мне казалось, это именно настройки. То есть, настройки от _программиста_ (а не от админа), которые задаются при компиляции и типизированы. Могу ошибаться.